# Replace `base` conda environment with other environment

Tags: conda

I realize this question may have been asked in the distant past, but `conda` has changed a lot and I still cannot find a way to replace the `base` environment with another named environment on the same machine. I realize I can do `conda activate other_environment` but that's not the same as changing the `base` environment. Thanks!

Comment: I have exactly the question as yours!

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are using either Mac or a Linux distro, and that by 'replace the base environment' you mean a different environment is loaded by default when you open a terminal window.

When you open a terminal, a special file called .zshrc or .bashrc runs, depending on your shell. This is in your home directory.

Open it and take a look. There should be some lines initialising conda.
An easy (but possibly dirty) way to replace base environment is by adding the line

```
conda activate other_environment
```

at the bottom of the file, to automatically activate the environment.

Finally, as suggested by @merv, run the following line to stop conda from activating base automatically.

`conda config --set auto_activate_base false`

Comment: Isn't that what I said? add the line ... below the lines initializing conda (so it isn't in a managed place) in .zshrc or .bashrc. Or can it be read in a different way? Thats what i meant though. I'm going to add it in to make it clearer

Comment: Sorry about that - yes, I didn't read carefully enough. All good!